# How do you differentiate between names, places, and things?

Tags: nlp

Here is a list of proper nouns taken from The Lord of the Rings. I was wondering if there is a good way to sort them based on whether they refer to a person, place or thing. Does there exist a natural language processing library that can do this? Is there a way to differentiate between places, names, and things?

Shire, Tookland, Bagginses, Boffins, Marches, Buckland, Fornost, Norbury, Hobbits, Took, Thain, Oldbucks, Hobbitry, Thainship, Isengrim, Michel, Delving, Midsummer, Postmaster, Shirriff, Farthing, Bounders, Bilbo, Frodo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're talking about [Named Entity Recognition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named-entity_recognition). It is the task of information extraction that seeks to locate and classify piece of text into predefined categories such as pre-defined names, location, organizations, time expressions, monetary values, etc. You can either do that by unsupervised methods using a dictionary such as the words you have. Or though supervised methods, using methods such as CRFs, Neural Networks etc. But you need a list of predefined sentences with the respective annotated names and classes. In this example [here](https://nabeel-oz.github.io/qlik-py-tools/docs/NER.html#ner-on-the-lord-of-the-rings), using Spacy (A NLP library), the authors applied NER to Lord of the rings novels. You can read more in the link.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:
Named-entity recognition (NER) (also known as entity identification, entity chunking and entity extraction) is a subtask of information extraction that seeks to locate and classify named entity mentioned in unstructured text into pre-defined categories such as person names, organizations, locations, medical codes, time expressions, quantities, monetary values, percentages, etc.

Wikipedia link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named-entity_recognition

Named Entity Recognition (NER) is a standard NLP problem which involves spotting named entities (people, places, organizations etc.) from a chunk of text, and classifying them into a predefined set of categories. Some of the practical applications of NER include:

Scanning news articles for the people, organizations and locations reported.
Providing concise features for search optimization: instead of searching the entire content, one may simply search for the major entities involved.
Quickly retrieving geographical locations talked about in Twitter posts.
NER with spaCy
spaCy is regarded as the fastest NLP framework in Python, with single optimized functions for each of the NLP tasks it implements. Being easy to learn and use, one can easily perform simple tasks using a few lines of code.

Installation :

```
!pip install spacy
!python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm

import spacy 
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm') 
sentence = "Apple is looking at buying U.K. startup for $1 billion"
doc = nlp(sentence) 
for ent in doc.ents: 
    print(ent.text, ent.start_char, ent.end_char, ent.label_)
```

Output:

Apple 0 5 ORG
U.K. 27 31 GPE
$1 billion 44 54 MONEY

In the output, the first column specifies the entity, the next two columns the start and end characters within the sentence/document, and the final column specifies the category.

Further, it is interesting to note that spaCy’s NER model uses capitalization as one of the cues to identify named entities. The same example, when tested with a slight modification, produces a different result.